# How to fix error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard' in Python?

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm using Anaconda in base environment (version 3.9.7), getting that same error of keyboard. I did import keyboard in the script, installed keyboard library but then Nothing Fix, it keeps giving me same error over again.

As you can see, I have installed keyboard already. Is there a way to fix that issue?

python is using path /home/user/anaconda3/bin/python

```
$ conda list | grep keyboard
keyboard                  0.13.5           py39hf3d152e_1    conda-forge

$ sudo python keytest.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Learn/Python/keytest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import keyboard
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keyboard'
```

Code:

```
import keyboard

keyboard.write("Tutorialspoint\n")

# It writes end of line
keyboard.press_and_release('shift + o, shift + y, \n')
keyboard.press_and_release('k, j')

# it blocks until ctrl
keyboard.wait('Ctrl')
```

Comment: I would expect a module that you're importing to have a .py suffix. Not sure here but do you need to actually install keyboard with pip install keyboard?

Comment: You're running your script with `sudo`, which means either your Python interpreter is probably different, or it's not reading your user `site-packages`.

Comment: If I don't use sudo python.. it will give that error portError: You must be root to use this library on linux.

Comment: I found and fixed my issue. The problem was I had two different python versions installed one old 2.7 and one new version 3.9 also pip got conflicted. I had to remove both and reinstall Only one new. After installed, it works fine with sudo python. It can't run without it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The same thing has happened to me with the same version of the lib, but in VScode and in Ubuntu terminal 22.04.2. If this is a bug, I think you should open an issue on github and expect to have a reply for the maintainer to see if it can be fixed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).